# How can I match mixed whitespace and () in Perl?

Tags: regex, perl

How do I improve my Perl regex to handle the `__DATA__` below?

```
my ($type, $value) =~ /<(\w+)\s+(.*?)\(\)>/;  

__DATA__
<dynamic DynamicVar>
<dynamic DynamicVar > # not need attache the blackspace to $value when return
<dynamic DynamicFun()>
<dynamic DynamicFun() > # not need attache the blackspace to $value when return
```

I want to return the `$type` and `$value` as this format `<$type $value>`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Rather than worrying about the details of the contents, just match anything inside the brackets.

```
my($type, $value) = m{< (\w+) \s+ (.*?) \s* >}x;
```

`.*?` means to match anything *non-greedy* which means it will look for the first thing to match, rather than the longest.  This means it won't pick up whitespace at the end, it will leave it to the `\s*`.  It also means it won't be fooled by `<foo bar> and then a >`.

Answer (score 4):

you have got your answer, but here's another way, with lesser regex.

```
while(<DATA>){
    chomp;
    s/[<>]//g;
    my ($type, $value) = split /\s+/ ;
    print "type: $type\n";
    print "value: $value\n";
}
```

Comment: This is very clever, but very brittle.  It relies on that there will always be exactly two whitespace separated things on each line and it will be the first thing on the line.  `<thing> msg`, `<thing func(args, and, stuff)> msg`, `msg and more`, `<thing>` will all cause it to fail and fail *SILENTLY*.

Answer (score 1):

Try this regular expression:

```
/<(\w+)\s+(.*?)(?:\s*\(\)\s*)?>/
```

But I would also replace `.*?` with something more specific. If you just expect word characters, you could also use `\w+` here.

Comment: Hi Gumbo, I tested your script, The return value can't join **()** . i.e. Return `value=DynamicFun`. Not return `value=DynamicFun()`.